# How use this code in .net core 2.2 (HttpContext.Request.Current.Session[key])

Tags: .net-core

I am unable to this code in .net core 2.2 version 
HttpContext.Current.Session["key"]

HttpContext.Current.Session["key"]

HttpContext.Current.Session["key"]

Answer (score 0):

In .NET Core there is no static `HttpContext.Current` anymore, because .NET Core has a built in Dependency Injection system that is used inside ASP.NET Core.

If your code is inside the usual HTTP request scope (middleware, controller, view, etc.), there is a `HttpContext` property available with the current HttpContext.
Otherwise you can access the HTTP context with `IHttpContextAccessor` (injected by DI).

You find all the details here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-2.2

In case you have the HttpContext but Session is null, then you have to enable the Session: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-2.2#session-state